# Oracle SQL - Regex to search columns with only 1 letter

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to to create a regex to find all columns that only have a single character (`[A-Z]`) as name, like `N` or `M` but not `NM`.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE Name REGEXP '^[A-Z]'
```

But it's not displaying the expected result.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Anchor to the end of the value? `'^[A-Z]$'`

Comment: @vkp: if name have 3 entry
N
M
NM
NMA
so output should be 
N and M only

Comment: where Name between 'A' and 'Z' and length(name) = 1

Comment: REGEXP is not Oracle function but MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try `^[A-Z]$`.
You then state that this character is first and also last character of the value.

Answer (score 0):

The regex functions in Oracle work only on one column. So, to search for just one character in a column, you would do the following:

```
select * from yourTable where REGEXP_LIKE (col1, '^[A-z]$');
```

Now, to search all the char/varchar columns on your table, you'll need to chain the regex expressions together, like so:

```
select * from yourTable where REGEXP_LIKE (col1, '^[A-z]$') or REGEXP_LIKE (col3, '^[A-z]$');
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL solution:
where name in ('N','M')

Comment: No Its not necessary it will be N or M. I can be any character from A-Z. Condition is its should only be of 1 charater